# Python Libraries on MacOS

Tags: python, macos

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -u -
```

I have tried everything pip then python version and nothing works.MacOS has a preinstalled python 2.7 so maybe that's the problem. please any help would be appreciated because I cannot download any libraries.

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: i cant it has too manu characters

Comment: Then put is as many of those from the end as possible.

Comment: pip-install-_tj9d_ie/pygame_d8255a281e094a058f49b33610ede2a5/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__,

Comment: "'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/q6/n0zxm8_57fq8r5jfj5fdw0ww0000gn/T/pip-record-aurp88vh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pygame Check the logs for full command output.